# Using an out parameter from an execute immediate statement that calls a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure that has an execute immediate statement. Within that execute immediate statement calls a procedure that has two out parameters. I'm having trouble trying to obtain those out parameters to be used in the procedure calling the execute immediate statement.

```
execute_stmt := 'DECLARE pi_error_log_rec error_log%ROWTYPE; p_plan_id NUMBER; begin SCHEMA.PACKAGE_NAME.' ||
                PROCEDURE || '(' ||
                p_audit_log_id || ', ' ||
                V_PARAMETER1 || ', ' || '''' ||
                V_PARAMETER2 || '''' ||
                ', p_plan_id, pi_error_log_rec); end;';
execute immediate execute_stmt;

if(pi_error_log_rec.error_text IS NOT NULL) THEN
  --do stuff;
ELSE
  --do stuff;
```

The out parameters are `p_plan_id` and `pi_error_log_rec`, the remaining are IN parameters. So I need to obtain those two outputs for use inside the procedure calling this execute immediate. But it's not setting the output in the variable. Am I missing a step or should I use a different approach in using out parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

```
execute_stmt := 'Begin SCHEMA.PACKAGE_NAME.PROCEDURE(:p_audit_log_id, :V_PARAMETER1, :V_PARAMETER2); END;';
execute immediate execute_stmt USING IN p_audit_log_id, OUT pi_error_log_rec, OUT p_plan_id;
```

Since Oracle 12c you can also fetch PL/SQL datatypes (like `RECORDS`, `BOOLEAN`) into dynamic SQL. In earlier versions you where limited to SQL datatypes only (like `NUMBER`, `VARCHAR2`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you.  This solved my problem.  But I think it's true about record types.  I got an error saying it must use sql types.